# How can I correct an 'only one socket usage of each address error' caused by a process being spawned within a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, multiprocessing, twitch

Currently, I am trying to develop a server framework which passes messages from twitch to other machines on a local network. I have a class called server and below I have a rudimentary example which demonstrates the problem I am running into. The issue is that the `twitch_socket` is being created twice and bound to the address/port. My expected result is that the socket would be shared between the child processes of the Server class. How can I modify the class, or even get rid of it entirely, so that the Processes would be able to share sockets between them?

```
import multiprocessing
import socket
import re
from BotPass import PASSWORD
def send_message(socketobj, message):
    'Sends a str as bytes through socket'
     message = message.encode()
     socketobj.sendall(message)
def recv_message(socketobj):
    'Receives a str as bytes though socket'
    return socketobj.recv(2048).decode()
class Server:
    'Handles receiving messages from twitch and directs messages from clients'
    twitch_socket = socket.socket()
    twitch_socket.connect(('irc.chat.twitch.tv', 6667))
    send_message(twitch_socket, 'PASS %s\r\n' % (PASSWORD))
    send_message(twitch_socket, 'NICK %s\r\n' % ('squid_coin_bot'))
    send_message(twitch_socket, 'JOIN #jtv\r\n')
    send_message(twitch_socket, 'CAP REQ :twitch.tv/commands\r\n')
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('', 9999))
    work_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    #Queue of messages from twitch
    worker_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    #Queue of free client socket objects
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    #Queue of what to send back to twitch
    def start():
        accept_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=Server.accept_connections)
        # *This is most likely where the issue is occurring*
        accept_process.daemon = True
        accept_process.start()
    def accept_connections():
         ''
        Server.server_socket.listen(10)
        while 1:
            (clientsocket, clientaddr) = Server.server_socket.accept()
            # What I believe I am referencing here is the server socket which is inherent to the Server class
            if re.match(r'192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', clientaddr[0])\
             or clientaddr[0] == '127.0.0.1':
                Server.worker_queue.put(clientsocket)
            else:
                clientsocket.close()
Server.start()
input()
```

Output in Console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\twitch-market\server.py", line 18, in <module>
    class Server:
  File "C:\twitch-market\server.py", line 27, in Server
    server_socket.bind(('', 9999))
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` 
This is because the previous execution has left the socket in a `TIME_WAIT` state, and can’t be immediately reused.the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag tells the kernel to reuse a local socket in `TIME_WAIT` state, without waiting for its natural timeout to expire.